# Changing logo based on incoming domain using php

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am trying to change the logo based on what domain the visitor is using to view the website. I found some code in another topic on this site, but i was unable to make it work, so i was wondering if anyone of you can see what i'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function logoSwap(){
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'liceng.dk': 
        $logo = "http://www.liceng.dk/images/liceng-logo.png";
    break;
    case 'www.liceng.dk':
        $logo = "http://www.liceng.dk/images/liceng-logo.png";
    break;
    case 'licenergy.co.uk':
        $logo = "http://www.liceng.dk/images/licenergy-logo.jpg";
    break;
    case 'www.licenergy.co.uk':
        $logo = "http://www.liceng.dk/images/licenergy-logo.jpg";
    break;
    case 'http://licenergy.co.uk/':
        $logo = "http://www.liceng.dk/images/licenergy-logo.jpg";
    break;
    default:
        $logo = "http://www.liceng.dk/images/liceng-logo.png";
    break;

};
return $logo;
}
?>
<?php 
   if(!empty($image)) {
      echo '<h1>LIC Engineering A/S</h1>';
   }
   else {
      echo '<img src="'.logoSwap().'" alt="LICeng logo">';
   }
?>
```

Shouldn't it work? You can check the site here: www.liceng.dk

Comment: What doesn't work?  Debug, don't expect us to go to your site to research your problem.

Comment: So what logo _do_ you see?

Comment: It probably has to do with loading the page within an iframe, so the host never changes.

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm just seeing the http://www.liceng.dk/images/liceng-logo.png image all the time. Like it's only using the first cast. Cause i tried changing the image in the first case, and it uses that, no matter if i try domain www.licenergy.co.uk :( My php is not so good sorry

Comment: Can you post what's in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` at the time you call `logoSwap()` for each page?

Comment: I did that @KevinStich Stitch, apparently im at the www.liceng.dk domain, even if the URL says www.licenergy.co.uk. Do you know what makes that happen?

Comment: For that, we would need to know what page(s) this php code is being run on and their code. This is almost certainly up to how you are getting to the logoSwap() call. It could easily be what @aynber suggested with an iframe.